# Resigning iOS app "Product identifiers don't match"

Tags: ios

My agency uses a 3rd party to build mobile apps for our websites. Currently I'm trying to re-sign an app using this tutorial: http://dev.mlsdigital.net/posts/how-to-resign-an-ios-app-from-external-developers/. I've gone through all of the steps exactly like they describe, but when I click ReSign! in the iReSign app, I get an alert that says "Product identifiers don't match" and the signing process stops. It's a pretty vague error message, but can anyone tell me what this error refers to and what I can do to fix it?

Answer (score 2):

This issue will occur when you try to resign the IPA with different **application-identifier**. The IPA file contains ***.plist** file. You need to update that application-identifier in the plist file with what you have in your account through which you want to perform resigning of IPA.